# Path of image in html file when i load on android webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have some html content which has to be displayed on android webview. Here is my code to display the content on webview

```
myBrowser.loadDataWithBaseURL("", myFormHTMLContent , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I have few img tags in html content. How can i specify the src for those? I tried this .. src = "/mnt/sdcard/myDir/test.gif". But its not loading that image. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
src = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"myDir/test.gif"
```

Comment: but when android version changes then it will not work...that code gives the SD Card directory path dynamically....

Comment: hello sachi if you satisfy with my answer then put the "Green Right Sign"...for this answer....